# convolutional neural network image recognition

Tags: tensorflow

Currently I am working on a project with convolutional network using tensorflow and I have set up the network and now i need to train it. I don't have a clue of how could the image should be for training. Like how much of % of the image the object is training on. 
It's a cigarette that I have to detect and I have tried around 280 individual pictures where the cigarette is about2-5% of the image. I'm thinking of scrapping those pictures and take new one where the cigarette is about 30-50% of the image. 
All the pictures are taking outside on the street environment.

So my question is: are there are any kind of rule regarding good pictures in a training set?
I will report back when I have tried my own solution

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KjTfes4 Here is an example of what kind of pictures i am trying on

Comment: What task are you solving, is it just a binary classification, yes/no for cigarette? If so, what you describe is called imbalanced training set and should be solved... Can you collect/make more images when cigarette is present?

Answer (score 0):

The object you are trying to recognise is too small. In the [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYGo9.jpg), I think first one will be the best bet for you. Convolution neural network works by doing convolution operations on image pixels. In the second picture, background is too large compared to the object you are trying to recongise. Training on such data will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to answer your rule question:
Make sure that cigarette occupies maximum region of the Image. It can be 50% to 90% (with experience). You can still identify cigarettes with 2 to 3 % area, but you need millions of images with varying backgrounds.

CNN learns from the input image. Looking at the sample images you shared (I guess all the images are taken from road side platforms and grass areas). CNN may not learn to find the cigarette, instead it will learn to detect the common background, if your background occupies maximum area of the image. Please make sure to keep different background patterns.